# Java: An error without an issue concering Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, runtime-error

My code:

```
package data;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private JFrame frame;
    private Hikari hikari = new Hikari(this);
    private BufferedImage biHikari;

    private boolean running = false;
    private double fps = 10;
    private double millUpdates = 1000 / fps;
    long lastUpdate;
    long lastTick;
    int count = 0;

    public Main() {
        start();
        frame = new JFrame("Project Darkness");
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

public void run() {
    lastUpdate = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() / millUpdates);
    lastTick = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    while (running) {
        if (toUpdate("Update")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                biHikari = hikari.getFrame(1);
                g.drawImage(biHikari, hikari.getX(), hikari.getY(), null);

        }
        toUpdate("Tick");
    }
}

private boolean toUpdate(String string) {
    switch (string) {
    case "Update":
        long thisUpdate = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() / millUpdates);
        if (thisUpdate != lastUpdate) {
            lastUpdate = thisUpdate;
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case "Tick":
        long thisTick = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        if (thisTick != lastTick) {
            lastTick = thisTick;
            System.out.println(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args0) {
    new Main().start();
}

}
```

The error is from these lines:

```
Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
while (running) {
    if (toUpdate("Update")) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            biHikari = hikari.getFrame(1);
            g.drawImage(biHikari, hikari.getX(), hikari.getY(), null);

    }
```

And the error itself is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at data.Main.run(Main.java:57)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 57 being

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

It works perfectly how it's meant to but an error still shows upwhen trying to draw to screen even though it still draws what it's told, the background is made black and then it draws biHiakri. Why does it come up with this error?

Comment: [getGraphics()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics()) returns `null` if the `Component` is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you start you call `getGraphics()` before the canvas is even visible, since `run()` is called (in `start()`) before adding the canvas to the frame.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics()) you can see, that it returns `null` in such cases.

Instead call `start()` at the end of the constructor (and don't call it in the `main()`, you call it twice - if you notice). Or remove `start()` completely from constructor, and let it all up to the `main()`. This insures that `getGraphics()` is called *after* added to frame.

Comment: I did not notice that, removing start(); from Main() worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself occures, because you try to generate a graphics-object from a component before adding it to a frame. If the component has no parent, `getGraphics()` will always return null. You'd have to start the thread **after** creating the ui. **But** you should never use this way to render a component anyways. Create an own component and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead and do the painting inside this method.